# descriptor 'join' requires a 'unicode' object but received a 'str'

Tags: python

Code adapted from [here](http://wiki.geany.org/howtos/convert_camelcase):

```
#from 'foo_bar' to 'Foo.Bar'
def lower_case_underscore_to_camel_case(self, string):
  print string
  class_ = string.__class__
  return class_.join('.', map(class_.capitalize, string.split('_')))
```

Output:

```
client_area
TypeError: descriptor 'join' requires a 'unicode' object but received a 'str'
```

Especially disappointing since the source code states:

> """Convert string or unicode from lower-case underscore to camel-case"""

How to fix this?

---

Easy fix:

```
return str.join('.', map(class_.capitalize, string.split('_')))
```

Could anyone explain me the overall process?

Comment: The "easy fix" you have just intruduced is not actually a fix. What part of the process you do not understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems to introduce unnecessary complexity, but you can do it like that:

```
#from 'foo_bar' to 'FooBar'
def lower_case_underscore_to_camel_case(self, string):
  print string
  class_ = string.__class__
  return class_.join(class_('.'), map(class_.capitalize, string.split('_')))
```

And you could actually shorten the last line to be:

```
return class_('.').join(map(class_.capitalize, string.split('_')))
```

Also, judging from the code, you will receive something like "`Foo.Bar`" (notice a dot) from "`foo_bar`".