# Pattern web unable to locate elements by class names

Tags: python, python-pattern

I'm trying to identify DOM elements by class name, but I'm not able to use the pattern.web as described [in the docs](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-web#DOM) (I'm also running code that I've used before, so it did work at some point).

```
from pattern.web import DOM

html = """<html><head><title>pattern.web | CLiPS</title></head>
<body>
  <div class="class1 class2 class3">
    <form action="/pages/pattern-web"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="search-block-form">
      <div>
        <label for="edit-search-block-form-1">Search this site: </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body></html>"""

dom = DOM(html)
print "Search Results by Method:"
print 'tag[attr="value"] Notation Results:'
print dom('div[class="class1 class2 class3"]')
print 
print 'tag.class Notation Results:'
print dom('div.class1')
print
print 'By class, no tag results:'
print dom.by_class('class1')
print 
print 'Looping through all divs and printing matching results:'
for i in dom('div'):
    if 'class' in i.attrs and i.attrs['class'] == 'class1 class2 class3':
        print i.attrs
```

Note that (`Element` and `DOM` functions are interchangeable and give the same results). The result is this:

```
Search Results by Method:
tag[attr="value"] Notation Results:
[]

tag.class Notation Results:
[]

By class, no tag results:
[Element(tag='div')]

Looping through all divs and printing matching results:
{u'class': u'class1 class2 class3'}
```

As you can see, looking it up using the `tag.class` notation and the `tag[attr="value"]` notation both give empty results, but `by_class` returns one result. Clearly elements with those attributes exist. How do I search for all the divs that have all 3 classes?

In the past, I've been able to search using `dom('div.class1.class2.class3')` to identify a div with all 3 classes. Not only does this not work, it's also giving me unicode errors (it appears that the second period causes a unicode error) : `TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'`

Comment: I tried that actually, they behave the same / did not make a difference. I'm starting to think the latest version of pattern.web does not support search by multiple class names.

Comment: Real data would be uniquely identifying, I can't do that @stovfl. What I've shared is real data just replaced to be anonymous.

Comment: Thanks for your help @stovfl. I updated the code and expected results, and clarified one of the things that was causing an error.

Comment: That would only work in this example. If I had `<div class='class1 class4'></div> <div class='class1 class2 class3'></div>` I'd only want the second one. With broader-than-desired criteria, if there's more than one match I can't be sure that it's what I"m looking for.

Comment: I assume you have tried `dom.by_class('class1 class2 class3')` already. You want to use **CSS selector**, according to the doc you have to do 1. `element = Element(html)` 2. `element('div[class="class1 class2 class3"]')`. I'm off!

Comment: Yep, tried all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: In the past, I've been able to search using `dom('div.class1.class2.class3')` to identify a div with all 3 classes.

---

> Reading the Source [github.com/clips/pattern/blob/master/pattern/web](https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/master/pattern/web/__init__.py),
>   found, it's only a wrapper using `Beautiful Soup`.
>
> > # Beautiful Soup is wrapped in DOM, Element and Text classes, resembling the Javascript DOM.
> >     # Beautiful Soup can also be used directly

---

> It's a known Issue, see SO:
>   [Beautiful soup find_all doesn't find CSS selector with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602747/beautiful-soup-find-all-doesnt-find-css-selector-with-multiple-classes)

The workaround ist to use `.select(...)` instead of `.find_all(...)`,
didn't find `.select(...)` in `pattern.web`

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<html><head><title>pattern.web | CLiPS</title></head>
  <body>
    <div class="class1 class4">
      <form action="/pages/pattern-web"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="search-block-form">
        <div class="class1 class2 class3">
          <label for="edit-search-block-form-1">Search this site: </label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</body></html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div = soup.select('div.class1.class2')
print("{}".format(div))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> [<div class="class1 class2 class3">
> <label for="edit-search-block-form-1">Search this site: </label>
> </div>]
> ```

---

> **Question**: it's also giving me unicode errors (it appears that the second period causes a unicode error) :
>
> ```
> TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'
> ```

It's unknown, if this `TypeError` is from `pattern.web` or `Beautiful Soup`.
According to this SO:[descriptor-join-requires-a-unicode-object-but-received-a-str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575879/descriptor-join-requires-a-unicode-object-but-received-a-str) it's a standard Python message.

---

Using `pattern.web` from GitHub, the results are as expected:

```
from pattern.web import Element

elements = Element(html)
print("Search Results by Method:")
print('tag[attr="value"] Notation\tResults:{}'
    .format(elements('div[class="class1 class2 class3"]')))

print('tag.class Notation \t\t\tResults:{}'
    .format(elements('div.class1.class2.class3')))

print('By class, no tag \t\t\tResults:{}'
    .format(elements.by_class('class1 class2 class3')))

print('Looping through all divs and printing matching results:')
for i in elements('div'):
    if 'class' in i.attrs:
        if " ".join(i.attrs['class']) == 'class1 class2 class3':
            print("\tmatch:{}".format(i.attrs))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Search Results by Method:
> tag[attr="value"] Notation  Results:{'class': ['class1', 'class2', 'class3']}
> tag.class Notation          Results:{'class': ['class1', 'class2', 'class3']}
> By class, no tag            Results:{'class': ['class1', 'class2', 'class3']}
> Looping through all divs and printing matching results:
>     match:{'class': ['class1', 'class2', 'class3']}
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.5.3 - pattern.web:3.6 - bs4:4.5.3***

Comment: Very helpful thank you. I didn't know pattern.web was built on top of it, it was introduced to me as an alternative!

Comment: @AUser: Updated my Answer, using `pattern.web` from GitHub, i got results as expected. Your `TypeError` seems to be version dependent.